# Do we need to hit server for reset of form

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, hibernate, spring-mvc

Do we need to really hit the server for resetting the form in a web application?
My application has front end angular js
Backened rest based java..
I am using spring security for authentication.
After login i have many forms in different menus.
Which will all then operations like create update delete.

Is there any necessity to reset form in server side? Any way resetting the form in ui side?

Answer (score 0):

Hitting sever is never required on resetting form.

Resetting form means removing data from form Eg. username,password etc
Hitting server means checking ,deleteing, updating , reading details from server otherwise server hit is not required

Eg. User entering username, password do not interact with server but when click on login  then data goes to server because thats server which actually contains user details

Hope this helps